# How can I make json4s extract fail if json doesn't contain field

Tags: json, scala, deserialization, json4s

I have a case class that only is a wrapper of a collection like this:

```
case class MyClass(list: List[String])
```

If I now try do deserialize some arbitrary json into this case class it doesn't fail if the list field is missing.
Is it possible to force it to fail during extraction?

Code example:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

val json = parse("""{ "name": "joe" }""")

case class MyClass(list: List[String])

val myClass = json.extract[MyClass] // Works!
assert(myClass.list.isEmpty)


case class MyClass2(test: String)
val myClass2 = json.extract[MyClass2] // Fails!
```

I need it to fail for the missing list field as it does for the string field.
Please help. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You can create a *`MyClass`* deserializer to deserialize *`MyClass`* with the *List* field, like:

```
  class MyClassSerializer extends Serializer[MyClass] {
    private val MyClassClass = classOf[MyClass]

    override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), MyClass] = {
      case (TypeInfo(MyClassClass, _), json) => json match {
        case JObject(JField("list", JArray(l)) :: _) =>
          MyClass(l.map(i => i.extract[String]))
        case x => throw new MappingException("Can't convert " + x + " to MyClass")
      }
    }

    override def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = ???
  }
```

The **cause** missing `List` field can't parse with `Exception` is in **Extraction.scala**:

```
  private class CollectionBuilder(json: JValue, tpe: ScalaType)(implicit formats: Formats) {
    private[this] val typeArg = tpe.typeArgs.head
    private[this] def mkCollection(constructor: Array[_] => Any) = {
      val array: Array[_] = json match {
        case JArray(arr)      => arr.map(extract(_, typeArg)).toArray
        case JNothing | JNull => Array[AnyRef]()
        case x                => fail("Expected collection but got " + x + " for root " + json + " and mapping " + tpe)
      }

      constructor(array)
    }
```

we can see the above code snippet, when we meet a collection in the *case class*, **Json4S** will retrieve the fields in the **Json AST** by the constructor parameter name(*list*), if it can't find the parameter name(*list*), it will return `JNothing`, but for `JNothing` in the above code snippet, it will create a new collection(`case JNothing | JNull => Array[AnyRef]()`) without throwing errors.